# img not displaying properly after closing bootstrap modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

First of all, I'm sorry if I'm not explaining correctly, please let me know if you don't understand something!

I have a gallery where every image have a hover effect, [this one](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index3.html). When I click the link, a bootstrap modal opens. Until here it works fine, but when I close the modal, the image is not displaying properly (first one should be same size and position than the second):
[image]

This is the HTML of this part:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 effect">
    <figure class="portfolio-item">
        <img src="images/carrera.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        <figcaption>
            <h3>hello</h3>
            <span>Hello</span>
            <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">More</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

CSS is pretty large:

```
.effect {
   padding: 10px 10px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
}
.effect figure {
   margin: 0;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align: left;
}
.effect figure img {
   max-width: 100%;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   transition: transform 0.4s;
}
.effect figure:hover img {
   transform: translateY(-25px);
}
.effect figcaption {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   padding: 7px;
   background: #26BC8A;
   color: #ed4e6e;
   height: 50px;
   top: auto;
   bottom: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   transform: translateY(100%);
   transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
}
.effect figure:hover figcaption {
   opacity: 1;
   transform: translateY(0);
   transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
}
.effect figcaption h3 {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   color: #C5DBCB;
   font-size: 14px;
}
.effect figcaption span {
   color: #F3D85E;
   font-size: 10px;
}
.effect figcaption a {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   padding: 2px 3px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   display: inline-block;
   background: #F3D85E;
   color: #26BC8A;
   position: absolute;
   right: 5px;
   bottom: 10px;
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

I'm trying to find a solution, however, I'm aware it's difficult to solve with that much code, so I will use another effect if it's too much problematic to answer.

Thanks very much guys

Comment: It will better if you can make a demo of your issue. You can use http://bootply.com

Answer (score 1):

Reason the image stuck up after modal closed, because of property `transform: translateY(100%);` and `transform: translateY(0%);` following selectors,

```
.effect figcaption {
    display: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    padding: 7px;
    background: #26BC8A;
    color: #ed4e6e;
    height: 50px;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
}
.effect figure:hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
}
```

[Fiddle with stuck images](https://jsfiddle.net/cf1mtdes/1/)

Remove these `transform` properties and it will fix the issue.

```
.effect figcaption {
    display: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    padding: 7px;
    background: #26BC8A;
    color: #ed4e6e;
    height: 50px;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
}
.effect figure:hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
}
```

[Working Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cf1mtdes/)

Comment: Hi Shehary, sorry to delete the question. I did because I had copied to cody to bootply. i wouldn't have that if I had seen you answered me!

Comment: With removing these transforms, the effect is not working properly, the image transition has no point now (translateY(-25px). there isn't any way to make figcaption appear as I want?